# Syntax error, unrecognized expression on find()

Tags: jquery

I have cookies:

```
 var city_id_cookie_load = Cookies.get('city_id_cookie')
```

Me need do this (or something like this)

```
var $cities = $('#cities');

$cities.on('click', 'a', function() {}).find(city_id_cookie_load).trigger('click');
```

How can I do this?

I try this:

```
var city_id_cookie_load = '$(' + "'" + '#' + Cookies.get('city_id_cookie') + "'" + ')';

$cities.on('click', 'a', function() 
$cities.on('click', 'a', function() {}).find(city_id_cookie_load).trigger('click');
```

But i get error:

**Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: $('#city-2')**

Comment: It looks like you're trying to build a jQuery object in a string which will never work. Try just building the selector: `'#' + Cookies.get('city_id_cookie')`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thanks! its work

Comment: Glad it fixed your problem. I added it as an answer for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to build a jQuery object in a string which will never work. Try just building the selector in the string:

```
var city_id_cookie_load =  '#' + Cookies.get('city_id_cookie')

$cities.on('click', 'a', function() {
  // your click handler logic...
}).find(city_id_cookie_load).trigger('click');
```